# Erro de exited, segmentation fault em C

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, memória, alocação

Estou tentando fazer uma função que me retorne uma data de acordo com um inteiro e sempre a aparece o erro:

> exited, segmentation fault

O código que criei é basicamente este:

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

 typedef struct{
   int dia;
   int mes;
   int ano;
 }Data;

 Data imprime_data(Data *datas, int n, int k);




#endif



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "data.h"

int main (void){
Data * datas;

int n;
scanf ("%d", &n);

datas = malloc(n * sizeof(Data));

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%d %d %d", &datas[i].dia, &datas[i].mes, &datas[i].ano); 
}



int k;

scanf("%d", &k);

Data  * teste;

* teste = imprime_data(datas, n, k);


for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    
    printf("%d %d %d", teste[i].dia, teste[i].mes, teste[i].ano);

}   

    


return 0;
}


#include "data.h"


Data imprime_data(Data *datas, int n, int k){

Data  * teste;




for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    
    if(datas[i].dia % 10 <= k && datas[i].mes % 10 <= k && datas[i].ano % 10 <= k){
        
        teste[i] = datas[i];
        
    

    } 
    
}
    




return *teste;


}
```

Comment: `teste` é apenas um ponteiro para uma variável do tipo `Data`, faltou alocar a memória.

Comment: consegue me dar um exemplo? sou iniciante e estou perdido em c kkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O maior problema é que não está alocando memória para o *array* chamado `teste` na função secundária, então estoura a memória.

E claro, eu liberei essa memória e a outra alocada. Para um exercício não causa problema, mas em outros código pode causar, então acostume fazer certo.

Mas o retorno da função também está errado e um bom compilador com as configurações certas nem deixaria compilar. Você quer retornar um *array*, então tem que retornar um ponteiro e não a estrutura simples.

Tem um outro problema, esse novo *array* terá um tamanho menor e você não pode tentar imprimí-lo inteiro. Coloquei mais um parâmetro para ter essa informação retornada. Pra falar a verdade eu faria de forma muito diferente disso, mas não sei o que o exercício pede de fato.

E claro, organizei o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} Data;
 
Data *imprime_data(Data *datas, int n, int k, int *total) {
    Data *teste = malloc(n * sizeof(Data));
    *total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (datas[i].dia % 10 <= k && datas[i].mes % 10 <= k && datas[i].ano % 10 <= k) {
            teste[i] = datas[i];
            (*total)++;
        }
    }
    return teste;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    Data *datas = malloc(n * sizeof(Data));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d %d %d", &datas[i].dia, &datas[i].mes, &datas[i].ano); 
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    int total = 0;
    Data *teste = imprime_data(datas, n, k, &total);
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) printf("%d %d %d", teste[i].dia, teste[i].mes, teste[i].ano);
    free(datas);
    free(teste);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gwnGB1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pvtzntge-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/NewArray.c).

Sugiro pegar exercícios mais simples até poder resolver por conta própria. Não pule conceitos, não tente fazer algo com mecanismos que ainda não domina.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela a resposta e pelo o conselho! mas ainda tenho uma dúvida preciso que o meu teste guarde na memoria mais de uma data, sabe como posso fazer isso? já que mesmo usando ele como vetor ele ainda não está guardando

Comment: Não sei, até porque existem milhões de formas de fazer isso, e pra mim já está fazendo, se não está, só você sabe o que quer fazer, e programar é antes de mais nada entender o problema de forma completa.

Answer (score 0):

> ainda tenho uma dúvida preciso que o meu teste guarde na memoria mais de uma data, sabe como posso fazer isso? já que mesmo usando ele como vetor ele ainda não está guardando

Tentei adivinhar o que pretende fazer com esse código e eu acho mesmo que você podia ter postado mais informação.

No entanto pelo que está lá e pelo que perguntou tem umas coisas que posso acrescentar

## O que você queria

- declarar um vetor de estruturas Data
- ler um valor `n` que vai ser o total de estruturas a ler
- alocar espaço para essas estruturas todas
- ler as Data uma a uma e gravar no vetor
- chamar `imprime_data()`, um tipo de filtro que vai extrair `k` dessas `n` estruturas de acordo com um critério que é `dia`, `mes` e `ano` módulo 10 menores ou iguais a `k`, e retornar como um vetor de `Data` que pode ter de 0 a `n` elementos. Isso porque pode ser que nenhum ou todos os `n` elementos lidos satisfaçam a esse critério

## Porque não deu certo

- quando você declara

`Data* datas;`

não está de fato declarando um vetor. Sequer está alocando espaço para uma `Data`. Só está declarando um ponteiro para `Data`, muito embora tenha até chamado de `datas` e depois declarado
   `datas = malloc(n * sizeof(Data));`

Mas `datas` é `Data*`. C não entende plural. `malloc()` vai sim alocar espaço para as `n` datas, mas você não vai poder *por a mão* nesse espaço.

Se você precisa de um vetor com 30 `Data` declara

```
Data data[30];
```

e pode acessar `data[0]` até `data[29]`. Note que usar o plural não é mais e sim menos legível porque vai usar uma data por vez apenas.

- você quer de fato `n` estruturas e então podia querer declarar

`Data data[n];`

Só que não pode. Tem que ser um número constante, como o 30 no exemplo acima, ou então alocar dinamicamente espaço para `n` estruturas `Data`.

- um outro problema é `imprime_data()`: ela vai separar `k` estruturas `Data` que atendam àquele critério folclórico do módulo 10. Só que o valor de `k` vai ficar para sempre enterrado dentro da função, já que a única coisa que retorna dela é um ponteiro para uma estrutura `Data`
- e `Data* teste;` declara um ponteiro para uma estrutura Data. Só uma. E sequer aloca memória para ela. E você precisa de mais de uma porque `k` valores podem atender ao seu critério, talvez nenhum, talvez todos os `n`
- `imprime_data()` é um nome bobinho, porque ela não imprime nada. Podia ser `filtra_datas()`
- e podia ter uma `imprime_data()` mesmo, que fizesse isso e você podia usar pra testar seu programa, chamando no início com as `n` estruturas lidas e depois com as `k` filtradas
- você não alocou memória direito e nem tentou liberar depois
- você não devia ler as `n` `Data` do teclado e sim de um arquivo porque é muito mais fácil e seguro de testar e reproduzir

## Como podia dar certo

Vou te explicar uma maneira de fazer isso e pode me dizer se era o que pretendia. E vou deixar um programa de exemplo porque é uma das coisas mais comuns de se errar em vetores de estruturas, então pode ajudar a outros

#### as mudanças

A maneira simples de usar um vetor de estruturas é a que o sistema prepara para todo programa C por exemplo. Veja o protótipo de main()
  `int main(argc, char** argv)`

No caso de `main()` é criado um vetor de estruturas `char*`, strings, com `argc` strings correspondendo aos parâmetros digitados na linha de comando que ativou o programa. No seu caso um vetor de estruturas `Data`, com `n` estruturas será lido no início, e depois um vetor de `Data` com `k` valores será criado pela função `imprime_data()`

- porque `argc` existe? É o mesmo problema de `k` em sua função `imprime_data()`: uma coisa é retornar um vetor com `k` estruturas, mas outra coisa é dizer quantas tem dentro do tal vetor
- O tipo para o vetor data é Data**
     `Data** data;`
- imprime_data() vai ser
     `Data** imprime_data(int n, Data** data, int* ext);`   
  o terceiro valor é passado por um ponteiro e assim pode retornar o total de valores extraídos do vetor original. O vetor em si vai estar no endereço que será retornado pela função. Uma solução mais elegante seria escrever o programa em torno de uma estrutura assim:

```
typedef struct
{
    int N;
    Data** data;
}   Datas;
```

e acho que já deu pra entender porque: essa é a unidade: um vetor de N estruturas. Sem novidades, já que é o que temos: `n` * `Data` em data e `k`* `Data` em `teste`

### Um programa EXEMPLO afinal

#### Arquivo de entrada do teste : "dados.txt"

```
    1 1 1
    2 2 2
    3 3 3
    4 4 4
    5 5 5
    6 6 6 
    7 7 7 
    8 8 8 
    9 9 9
```

#### A saída do programa para esse arquivo

```
  Total de valores a ler do arquivo: 9
  vai ler 9 datas de '../../../src/datas.txt'

Vetor com 9 datas:

   1: 1 1 1
   2: 2 2 2
   3: 3 3 3
   4: 4 4 4
   5: 5 5 5
   6: 6 6 6
   7: 7 7 7
   8: 8 8 8
   9: 9 9 9
----------

  Valor de 'k', a constante para a selecao: 4
  o valor de k: 4

Vetor com 4 datas:

   1: 1 1 1
   2: 2 2 2
   3: 3 3 3
   4: 4 4 4
----------
```

#### O programa

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
}   Data;

typedef struct
{   // exemplo mais legível
    int N;
    Data** data;
}   Datas;

Data**  imprime_data(int,Data**,int*); // filtra
int     mostra_data(int,Data**); // mostra na tela

int main(void)
{
    const char* padrao = "../../../src/datas.txt";
    FILE* entrada = fopen(padrao, "r");
    if (entrada == NULL)
    {
        printf("  nao abriu '%s'\n", padrao);
        return -1;
    };
    int n;
    int res = 0;
    printf("\n  Total de valores a ler do arquivo: ");
    while ((res = scanf("%d", &n)) != 1){}; // le n
    if (res != 1) return -2;
    printf("  vai ler %d datas de '%s'\n", n, padrao);
    Data** data = (Data**) malloc(n * sizeof(Data*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        data[i] = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
        res = fscanf(entrada, "%d %d %d",
            &data[i]->dia,
            &data[i]->mes,
            &data[i]->ano); // loop para ler k valido
    };  // for()
    fclose(entrada);
    mostra_data(n, data); // mostra o que leu
    int k;
    printf("\n  Valor de 'k', a constante para a selecao: ");

    while ((res = scanf("%d", &k)) != 1){}; // le k
    printf("  o valor de k: %d\n", k);
    Data** teste = imprime_data(n, data, &k);
    mostra_data(k, teste); // mostra o que selecionou

    // apaga os vetores
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) free(data[i]);
    free(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) free(teste[i]);
    free(teste);
    return 0;
}

Data** imprime_data(int n, Data** data, int* k)
{
    // para facilitar aloca com n valores
    Data** teste = (Data**)malloc(n * sizeof(Data*));
    int ext = 0; // vai contar o total de extraidos
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (
            data[i]->dia % 10 <= *k && 
            data[i]->mes % 10 <= *k && 
            data[i]->ano % 10 <= *k)
        {
             // ok: vai copiar esse
            teste[ext] = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
            *(teste[ext]) = *(data[i]); // copia esse
            ext += 1; // avanca k ou vai escrever em cima
        };  // if()
    };  // for()
    *k = ext; // vai retornar o valor
    // copiou *k elementos, entre 0 e n inclusive
    if (ext == 0)
    {   // nao tinha nenhum
        free(teste);
        return NULL;
    };
    if (ext == n) return teste; // todos foram copiados
    // libera via realloc() o que nao foi usado e retorna
    return (Data**)realloc(teste, ext * sizeof(Data*));
};  // imprime_data()

int mostra_data(int N, Data** V)
{
    // simplesmente mostra o vetor V de N datas na tela
    printf("\nVetor com %d datas:\n\n",N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%4d: %d %d %d\n", 1 + i,
            V[i]->dia, V[i]->mes, V[i]->ano
        );
    };  // for()
    printf("----------\n");
    return N;
};
```

Claro que o nome do arquivo deveria ser passado na linha de comando como parâmetro e não estar enterrado no programa...